# How to apply a custom mapping with current scripts

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using the code here [Mask Code](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney) and it works really well.

At the moment all my currencies are masked to two decimal places by default. Is there a way to have it masked sometimes and not masked sometimes?

For example, I only want it masked if there's trailing decimal. If my value model value is `300000.99` it should display as 300,000.99. That works perfectly fine. But lets say it's `300000.00` it should display only as `300,000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check your number using a [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator:

```
if(num % 1 == 0){...
```

Then we know that the number is a whole number, therefore you don't have to mask it.

Comment: I like the suggestion, it's just I'm not quite sure where to put what line of code. I've tried in all sorts of places but it doesn't fit nicely

Comment: If you provided a code sample, I could try and help, but I don't know how I could tell you where to put it if I don't know what your code looks like.